# Сочетаемость наречий "всегда и никогда" с глаголами при отрицании

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Можно сказать: **времени всегда не хватает и времени никогда не хватает.**

**Также:** ему это всегда не нравилось/никогда не нравилось, лидеров никогда не любят/всегда не любят; он всегда не доверял/никогда не доверял  рекламщикам.

Но такая **вариантность свойственна только некоторым глаголам,** остальные при отрицании сочетаются с наречием ***никогда,*** например: его никогда не бывает дома, он никогда не читает книг и т.д.

**Вопросы:** Какие глаголы допускают вариантность наречий  ***всегда/никогда*** и почему? Чем отличаются варианты по смыслу и стилю?

Answer (score 2):

Замечу в качестве отдельного наблюдения, что "всегда не" абсолютно не сочетается с глаголами совершенного вида. А "никогда не" с такими глаголами в разговорной речи встречается повсеместно (в художественной литературе редко, но в принципе считается допустимым).

Далее, мне удалось найти небольшое обсуждение этого вопроса во втором томе избранных трудов Ю.Д. Апресяна. Там указывается, что этот вопрос сложен и рассматриваются только его отдельные моменты. Я приведу выборочно пару цитат, не пытаясь дать полный связный ответ на поставленный вопрос.

> Те же рассуждения в принципе верны и для ГСП (глубинно-синтаксическое
>   представление). ГСП предложения *Иван всегда не ездит на такси*
>   абсолютно неправильно, потому что в нем нарушен некий сочетаемостный
>   запрет, состоящий в самом первом приближении в том, что общекванторное
>   слово (везде, все, всегда, всякий) не сочетается с **не**, если оба эти
>   слова зависят, непосредственно или опосредствованно, от одного и того
>   же предикатного слова.
>
> (**Сноска к сказанному выше.**) В действительности запрет носит
>   гораздо более сложный характер, особенно если учесть факторы (см.
>   раздел 4.3), от которых мы в этой работе решили отвлечься. Фразы типа
>   *Всегда он не просыпается во время* (с логическим ударением на общекванторном слове) допустимы в большей мере, чем фразы типа *Он
>   всегда не просыпается во время* (без логических ударений). В
>   противопоставительном контексте комбинация **всегда не**
>   представляется более допустимой, чем в нейтральном контексте; ср.
>   *Иван всегда не спит, когда другие давно спят*. Некоторые другие тонкости, связанные с употреблением слов этого типа в контексте
>   частицы **не**, обсуждаются в следующих работах: Seuren P. A. М.,
>   Negative's Travels, в: Semantic Syntax, Edited by Pieter A.V.Seuren,
>   Oxford, 1974. С. 197; Падучева Е. В. О семантике синтаксиса. Материалы
>   к трансформационной грамматике русского языка. М., 1974, С. 108-109.
>   Выскажем одно несогласие. Е. В. Падучева считает, что **всегда**
>   преобразуется в **никогда** "в контексте грамматического отрицания" и
>   говорит о "замещаемости слова **всегда** словом **никогда**" (С. 108),
>   называя их "контекстными синонимами". Это представляется нам
>   неточностью: **не** при **всегда** и при **никогда** выполняет
>   совершенно разные роли — смысловую в первом случае и чисто
>   грамматическую (своего рода согласовательную) во втором. Отрицание не
>   может поэтому рассматриваться как один и тот же элемент контекста.
>   **Всегда** и **никогда** — не синонимы, а антонимы. Отношение синонимии имеет место только между "словосочетанием" **всегда не** (со
>   смысловым **не!**) и словом **никогда** (см.об этом Апресян Ю. Д. Цит.
>   соч., С. .296, 331). В связи со сказанным в формальной модели лучше
>   иметь не одну трансформацию (**всегда** <=> **никогда** в "контексте
>   грамматического отрицания"), а две разных: **'всегда не'** <=>
>   **никогда** (на этапе СемП <=> ГСП) и **никогда** <=> **никогда не**.
>
> Заметим, в частности, что хотя русские слова **всегда** и **не** при
>   определенных условиях не сочетаются друг с другом, т. е. дают
>   неправильное ГСП, семантические слова (смыслы) '**всегда**' и '**не**'
>   в соответствующем СемПе идеально сочетаемы. Об этом свидетельствуют
>   безупречные в языковом отношении фразы типа *Петр всегда отсутствует*:
>   отсутствовать ='не присутствовать' и, следовательно, *Петр всегда
>   отсутствует* = '*Петр всегда не присутствует*'.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересно. Вопрос сложный, и никак общая картина не складывается, надо еще подумать.

Answer (score 1):

У глаголов в "позитивных" примерах можно отметить такие отличительные свойства:

1. Эти глаголы допускают утверждение своего отрицательного смысла, который позволяет распространить их на множественные однократные случаи.

> Он всегда не доверял = всякий раз, как ему предлагали нечто, он с
>   недоверием относился к рекламщикам.
>
> Ему всегда не нравилось = всякий раз, как он с этим сталкивался, ему
>   это не нравилось (он даже это как-то выражал).
>
> Лидеров всегда (везде, все, во всех смыслах и т. д.) не любят -
>   обобщающее утверждение "нелюбви" ("всегда" не имеет строго временного смысла; их не любят здесь, там, гнали тогда и сейчас; с ними пива не пьют и в долг им не дают - и так во всех случаях жизни).

2. Они не содержат в себе обобщающего значения "никогда", что делает возможным их сочетание с наречием "всегда".

Пример с "нечтением книг" не соответствует *первому* условию (нельзя утвердить отрицательный смысл "нечтения" или приписать его множественным случаям: "я пришёл к нему, а он не читает книгу"), а пример с "небыванием" - *второму*: "не бывает" уже содержит в себе смысл "никогда", не сочетающийся с наречием "всегда".

Comment: Да, спасибо. У меня сначала никакой версии не было, а сейчас отчасти обозначилась, но только проще и схематичнее, чем у Вас. Может быть, еще кто-нибудь ответит.